# Java Big Decimal problem

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am using java big decimal as follwing:

```
class test bigDecimal{

private BigDecimal decimalResult;


    public boolean iterate(String value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        System.out.println("value is: " + value);

        BigDecimal temp = new BigDecimal(value);

        System.out.println("temp val is: " + temp);
        if (decimalResult == null) {
            decimalResult = temp;
        } else {
            decimalResult = decimalResult.add(temp);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

}

all the strings that I am using to create big Decimal have scale of 6. For eg: 123456.678000, 456789.567890

But If I give a big list of strings as input and check the sum, I get output with 8 digits after decimal point. for eg. something like: 2939166.38847228.

I wonder why does BigDecimal change this scale ? all my input has scale of 6.

Any inputs are appreciated.
-thanks

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that shows this?

Comment: lol @ `Any inputs are appreciated` :)

Comment: Inputs are about 1 million such stribg values that are getting summed up as big decimal and getting printed as strings.

Answer (score 6):

Please read the javadoc for BigDecimal:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html
Internally all BigDecimals get converted to a some internal format.

If you want to get a specific format you have to call it appropriate.
You could use `scaleByPowerOfTen(int n)` with n=6 for example

Oh, and by the way never use `new BigDecimal`, use `BigDecimal.valueOf` instead.

EDIT:

`NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(); // use a locale here`
`String formated = df.format(myUnformatedBigDecimal);`

Comment: Regarding not using new, I have a string that I am using to create big decimal from string. valueOf only accepts long/double as input. In my case, input can be 21 characters that is more than what a long/double will hold.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem of internal representation. This way the BigDecimal.toString() works. It calls layoutChars(true) - the private method that formats number. It has hard coded scale of 6. But I think it does not matter. You do not really have to pint all digits. BigDecimal provides ability to calculate high precision numbers. That's what it does.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutly right. I thought of the internal representation of BigInteger.
You should use something like this:
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(); // use a locale here
String formated = df.format(myUnformatedBigDecimal);

Answer (score 0):

Big decimal is giving an exact output, but that output is more accurate than 6 digits, so the best way to get 6 digit output is removing the last 2 decimals by converting the BigDecimal into string and doing something like that:

```
    String myOutput = new 
    BigDecimal("1000.12345678").toString();
    myOutput = myOutput.substring(myOutput.length-2, 
     myOutput.length);
```